# Pass id or class name to points(ticks) inside canvas

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am using react-chartjs-2 to render charts and on clicking the active point it gets redirected to some other page.

```
 <Line
   id={'chartid'}
   data={data}
   options={options}
   getElementAtEvent={dataset => {
     // redirects to some other page
   }}
/>
```

Sample chart

[image: 1]

We are doing automation testing and  need to check if click is working or not.

Is there any option to add id/class to active elements inside the rendered canvas. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK every element has got `datasetIndex` and `index` properties related to the drawn dataset.
Emitting the `click` event on the canvas (a specific point) you could check that dataset index and index are what you are expecting